# Specificity of question vs near-duplicates?

Tags: discussion

## Scenario

In [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467428/how-to-computing-the-x-coordinate-of-the-nth-quantile-of-a-distribution-usi?noredirect=1#comment863743_467428) I ask for a solution that could be solved by selecting some distribution that satisfies some specified criteria and calculating the/a quantile position in python. For every distribution the computation to determine the quantile is different, so for each distribution the question would be unique and could be copied.

I think it would be interesting but bad to duplicate this question for example 20 times for 20 different distributions that satisfy the posed constraints. Hence I would think it is more valuable to ask a question that captures at least 1, just like it would when the distribution is specified, but allows answers for multiple distributions.

And I think this is the essence of the close vote: "We want single unique questions, not questions that elicit a list of different answers."

## Guidelines

In the [how to ask](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) it says: "be specific". Not "be as specific as possible". Additionally I have not found a deliberation on what is better, multiple nearly identical questions or a single encompassing question. Therefor, I would like to ask:

## Question

Assuming someone is, or I am, interested in [this same question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467428/how-to-computing-the-x-coordinate-of-the-nth-quantile-of-a-distribution-usi?noredirect=1#comment863743_467428) for (a) different distribution(s),
is it better to pick a single distribution and then copy the question for other distributions when interested, or give the liberty to allow any of the multiple possible distributions to be used to answer the question?

Comment: Could you give more detailed example, e.g. linking to a particular question that you have in mind?

Comment: Thank you, I included the reference to the particular question I had in mind, in the question.

Comment: [Glen_b's comment to your original question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467428/how-to-computing-the-x-coordinate-of-the-nth-quantile-of-a-distribution-usi?noredirect=1#comment863710_467428) gets to the point: when a question is posed in such generality that it will receive multiple different answers, depending on additional assumptions adopted by readers, then it is not sufficiently specific.

Comment: @whuber, thank you, that is clear, I will include a particular distribution when find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment by @whuber, when a question is posed in such generality that it will receive multiple different answers depending on additional assumptions adopted by readers, then it is not sufficiently specific.

This seems to imply that it is better to ask multiple near-copies of the question for different distributions, when relevant, than to allow for different answers by allowing readers to make additional assumptions leading to significantly different answers.

As a solution to the XY-problem I could include a specification for a specific distribution.